# What is wrong in these mysqli prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to make a registration script using PHP with Mysql database. The insertion cannot be done. If I register with an email-id which is already in the database, it is working fine. But, the script fails to insert new entries. It is returning 'bool(false)'. 
I've tried the to do the same using PDO. The insertion can't be done. So, I tried mysqli prepared statements instead and even this yields the same result. Here is the code.

```
<?php

$dbh = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');

if(isset($_POST['register'])){

        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $name = $_POST['$name'];
        $mail = $_POST['mail'];
        $passw = $_POST['passw'];
        $codeone = $_POST['codeone'];
        $descs = $_POST['desc'];
        $newstrings = 'specialstring';
        $encrypted_pass = crypt( $passw );

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT mail FROM userrecs WHERE mail=?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$mail);


        if($stmt->execute())
        {
        $stmt->store_result();
        $rows = $stmt->num_rows;
        if($rows == 1)
            {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['notification_one'] = 'bla';
                    header('location:/someplace');  
                 }

              else {
                    $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO userrecs (ip,name,mail,pass,codeone_one,desc_one,spcstrings) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
              $statement->bind_param('ssssiss',$ip,$name,$mail,$encrypted_pass,$codeone,$descs,$newstrings);

try {
    if($statement->execute())
    {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['noti_two'] = 'bla';
            header('location:/someplace');  
               }
               else
               {
               var_dump($statement->execute());
              $statement->errorInfo();
               }
    }
    catch(PDOException $pe) {
        echo "S";
    echo('Connection error, because: ' .$pe->getMessage());
    }       
              }
        }
    }
    else{
        header('location:/someplace');
    }
?>
```

**EDIT:**

This is the PDO-only code. I was mixing PDO and mysqli in the previous code.

```
<?php


$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=dbname;host=localhost';
$user = 'user';
$password = 'pass';
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

if(isset($_POST['regsubmit'])){

        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $name = $_POST['$name'];
        $mail = $_POST['mail'];
        $pass = $_POST['passw'];
        $codeone = $_POST['codeone'];
        $descs = $_POST['desc'];
        $newstrings = 'specialstring';
        $encrypted_pass = crypt( $passw );


        $sql = "SELECT mail FROM userrecs WHERE mail=:mail";
        $statement = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindValue(':mail',$mail,PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($statement->execute())
            {
              if($statement->rowCount() == 1)
                 {
                        session_start();
                    $_SESSION['noti_one'] = 'bla';
                    header('location:/someplace');  
                 }

              else {
                $sql2 = "INSERT INTO userrecs (ip,name,mail,pass,codeone_one,desc_one,spcstrings) VALUES (:ip,:name,:mail,:encrypted_pass,:codeone,:descs,:newstrings)";

                $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql2);
                $stmt->bindParam(':ip',$ip,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':name',$name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':mail',$mail,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':encrypted_pass',$encrypted_pass,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':codeone',$codeone,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':descs',$descs,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':newstrings',$temstr,PDO::PARAM_STR);

try {
    if($stmt->execute())
    {

            session_start();
            $_SESSION['noti_two'] = 'bla';
            header('location:/someplace');  
               }
               else
               {
               var_dump($stmt->execute());
              $stmt->errorInfo();
               }
    }
    catch(PDOException $pe) {
        echo "S";
    echo('Connection error, because: ' .$pe->getMessage());
    }
              }

        }
    }
    else{
        header('location:/someplace');
    }
?>
```

**Please ignore variable or table names**. I edited some of the names here.

Comment: ..can you proide the error message? Whats the output of $dbh->error?

Comment: You should tell mysqli to throw exceptions when something goes wrong: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing PDO and mysqli driver in the same script, this is not possible.

Please use either one but not both.

PDO is the prefferred extension.

---

EDIT:

In your query:

```
INSERT INTO userrecs (ip,name,mail,pass,codeone_one,desc_one,spcstrings) VALUES (...)
```

`NAME` is a [mysql reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html), you escape it by using backticks:

```
INSERT INTO userrecs (ip,`name`,mail,pass,codeone_one,desc_one,spcstrings) VALUES (...)
```

---

EDIT:

Change

```
var_dump($statement->execute());
$statement->errorInfo();
```

to

```
var_dump($statement->errorInfo());
```

---

EDIT:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=dbname;host=localhost';
$user = 'user';
$password = 'pass';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
if (isset($_POST['regsubmit'])) {
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT mail FROM userrecs WHERE mail=:mail";
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':mail', $_POST['mail'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        if ($stmt->execute() && $stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['noti_one'] = 'bla';
            header('location:/someplace');
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO userrecs (ip,name,mail,pass,codeone_one,desc_one,spcstrings) VALUES (:ip,:name,:mail,:encrypted_pass,:codeone,:descs,:newstrings)";
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindValue(':ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(':name', $_POST['$name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(':mail', $_POST['mail'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(':encrypted_pass', crypt($_POST['passw']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(':codeone', $_POST['codeone'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(':descs', $_POST['desc'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(':newstrings', 'specialstring', PDO::PARAM_STR);

            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['noti_two'] = 'bla';
                header('location:/someplace');
            } else {
                var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());
            }

        }
    } catch (PDOException $pe) {
        echo "S";
        echo('Connection error, because: ' . $pe->getMessage());
    }
} else {
    header('location:/someplace');
}
```

Comment: I'm messing it up. What else apart from 'PDOException' do I need to change? I actually have tried the whole thing in PDO too, and got the same problem.

Comment: Update your question with pdo only code we'll sort it out

Comment: I didn't use that name in my real code. I modified the names only for posting. The actual table name was 'user_names'.

Comment: Got this. 'array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL } '

Comment: @sofa_maniac do not forget `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` for PDO to report the errors back to you, see in my code right after the connections

Comment: I'm getting this output now : "SConnection error, because: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'mail' cannot be null"

Comment: the error info could not be any clearer, make sure mail is not null

Comment: 'mail' is not null. Neither are the other inputs. I deleted 'mail' and modified the code as necessary by removing 'mail' from the queries. Then it showed the same output, but for 'codeone'.

Comment: echo out the query and run it in your server `echo "INSERT INTO userrecs (ip,name,mail,pass,codeone_one,desc_one,spcstrings) VALUES ('".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."','".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['mail']."', '".crypt($_POST['passw'])."', '".$_POST['codeone']."', '".$_POST['desc']."', 'specialstring')";`

Comment: Im afraid I cannot be of anymore help, clear your question and show the updated code

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have an error in your logic.
Try this code and see what you get ...

```
<?php

$dbh = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');

if(isset($_POST['register'])) {

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $name = $_POST['$name'];
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    $passw = $_POST['passw'];
    $codeone = $_POST['codeone'];
    $descs = $_POST['desc'];
    $newstrings = 'specialstring';
    $encrypted_pass = crypt($passw);

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT mail FROM userrecs WHERE mail=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $mail);
    $test = $stmt->execute();   
    if($test) {
        $stmt->store_result();
        $rows = $stmt->num_rows;
        if($rows == 1) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['notification_one'] = 'bla';
            header('location:/someplace');
        } else {
            $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO userrecs (ip,name,mail,pass,codeone_one,desc_one,spcstrings) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $statement->bind_param('ssssiss', $ip, $name, $mail, $encrypted_pass, $codeone, $descs, $newstrings);

            try {
                if($statement->execute()) {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['noti_two'] = 'bla';
                    header('location:/someplace');
                } else {
                    var_dump($statement->execute());
                    $statement->errorInfo();
                }
            } catch (PDOException $pe) {
                echo "S";
                echo('Connection error, because: ' . $pe->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo "test is not ok";
        var_dump($test);
    }
} else {
    header('location:/someplace');
}
```

Comment: Same. Exactly the same results.